# Why radio buttons doesn't remain unchangeable and checked?

Tags: radio-button, checked, disabled-input

I'm new here and I'm writing my first php code. I want to prepare a multiple choice quiz in which, after click on a button at the end of the page, the radios button (the choices of the test) will remain checked and unchangeable. I simplify the code in this way:

```
<?php
$choice1 = "a";
$choice2 = "b";
?>

<form method="post" name="testForm" id="testForm">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a"
            <?php if(isset($_POST['test-result']) && $radioVal==$choice1){ echo "disabled='disabled' checked";}?>
            <?php if(isset($_POST['test-result']) && $radioVal<>$choice1){ echo "disabled='disabled'";}?>> 
            <?php echo "<span id='question'>". $choice1 ."</span>";?> </li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b"
            <?php if(isset($_POST['test-result']) && $radioVal==$choice2){ echo "disabled='disabled' checked";}?>
            <?php if(isset($_POST['test-result']) && $radioVal<>$choice2){ echo "disabled='disabled'";}?>> 
            <?php echo "<span id='question'>". $choice2 ."</span>";?> </li>
    </ul><br>
<button class='button' name='test-result'>Finaliza el test</button>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['test-result']))
    {
        $radioVal = $_POST["q1"];
    }
?>
```

However, after click on the button, all radios remain uncheged (and this is ok) but the choices made are not checked. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox is not showing checked because variable  $radioVal is set after input box. To resolve your  issue  could you please set $radioVal before from.

Comment: Sorry! but in my not simplify code the </form> tag was after $radioVal and it doesn't work. Thanks!